# MS Access Error in oledb

Tags: c#, oledb, ms-access-2013

My application was working fine with MS Access 2013 and c#, suddenly It started giving following exception "The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data".

I searched for this error, I got that reason for this is inserting string having length greater than 255 chars, but my string's length is 100.

Please help me in fixing this issue.

Following is code:

```
querySaveTweet.Parameters.Add("@tText", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = text.Substring(0, Math.Min(text.Length, 255));
```

Insert statement:

```
"INSERT into TempTweets (TText,other columns) VALUES (@tText,Others)";
```

I get the error on ExecuteNonQuery statement.
In Access column datatype is "Short Text"

--------------------FULL CODE--------------------------

```csharp
foreach (T tw in ts)
{
    try
    {
        string text = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tw.Text) ? null : Regex.Replace(tw.Text, @"(\n)", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline).Trim();
        string st = "INSERT into TT (T,TText,TS,U,Q,C,La,Lo,InR,InRe,InRep,Re,Ret,To)"
                            + "VALUES (@t,@tText,@tS,@u,@q,@c,@la,@lo,@inR,@inRe,@inRep,@re,@ret,@to)";                                   
        using (OleDbCommand qst = new OleDbCommand(st))
        {
            qst.Connection = openCon;
            qst.Parameters.Add("@t", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = tw.S;
            qst.Parameters.Add("@tText", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = text.Substring(0, Math.Min(text.Length, 255)); 
            qst.Parameters.Add("@tS", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = tw.TS;
            qst.Parameters.Add("@u", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = tw.U;
            qst.Parameters.Add("@q", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = q;                                        
            qst.Parameters.Add("@c", OleDbType.Date).Value = tw.C;
            qst.Parameters.Add("@la", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = tw.La;
            qst.Parameters.Add("@lo", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = tw.Lo;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tw.InReplyToScreenName))
            {
                tw.InReplyToScreenName = "";
            }
            qst.Parameters.Add("@inR", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = tw.InR;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tw.InReplyToStatusID))
            {
                tw.InReplyToStatusID = "";
            }
            qst.Parameters.Add("@inRe", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = tw.InRe;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tw.InReplyToUserID))
            {
                tw.InReplyToUserID = "";
            }
            qst.Parameters.Add("@inRep", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = tw.InRep;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tw.RetweetedStatus.StatusID))
            {
                tw.RetweetedStatus.StatusID = "";
            }
            qst.Parameters.Add("@re", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = tw.Re.StatusID;
            qst.Parameters.Add("@ret", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = tw.Ret.ToString();
            qst.Parameters.Add("@to", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = tw.To.ToString();

            qst.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        row++;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: What is the character limit in the column?  The error is telling you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: can you show what you are trying to insert and the code which accepts it.

Comment: Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: "The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add".  Without seeing code that would suggest that you tried to insert   more characters than your comment field type allowed.  Is your insert data 100 characters in length or is your column data 100 characters in length?

Comment: Can you confirm that your record is less than 4000 chars (Excluding Memo and OLE Object fields). Change few field to memo and then try.

Comment: can you update the question with actual sql statement and actual parameter adding code?